# Adjustment of multiple table on same page

Tags: tables

I have created a multiple page table (table1) which covers 1.5 pages and another table (table 2) after the end of the first table but the order of 2nd part of the 1st table comes after table 2.

```
 \usepackage{longtable}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{center}
 \begin{longtable}{p{4cm}|p{4cm}|p{4cm}}
 \caption{A simple longtable example}\\
 \hline
 \textbf{First entry} & \textbf{Second entry} & \textbf{Third entry}  \\
 \hline
 \endfirsthead
 \multicolumn{3}{c}%
 {\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\
 \hline
 \textbf{First entry} & \textbf{Second entry} & \textbf{Third entry}  \\
 \hline
  \endhead
  \hline \multicolumn{3}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
  \endfoot
  \hline
  \endlastfoot
  1 & 2 & 3  \\ 1 & 2 & 3  \\ 1 & 2 & 3  \\ 1 & 2 & 3  \\
  1 & 2 & 3  \\ 1 & 2 & 3  \\ 1 & 2 & 3  \\ 1 & 2 & 3  \\
  1 & 2 & 3  \\ 1 & 2 & 3  \\ 1 & 2 & 3  \\ 1 & 2 & 3  \\
  1 & 2 & 3  \\ 1 & 2 & 3  \\ 1 & 2 & 3  \\ 1 & 2 & 3  \\1 & 2 & 3  \\ 1 & 2 & 3  \\ 1 & 2 & 3  \\ 1 & 2 & 3  \\
1 & 2 & 3  \\ 1 & 2 & 3  \\ 1 & 2 & 3  \\ 1 & 2 & 3  \\
1 & 2 & 3  \\ 1 & 2 & 3  \\ 1 & 2 & 3  \\ 1 & 2 & 3  \\1 & 2 & 3  \\ 1 & 2 & 3  \\ 1 & 2 & 3  \\ 1 & 2 & 3  \\1 & 2 & 3  \\ 1 & 2 & 3  \\ 1 & 2 & 3  \\ 1 & 2 & 3  \\1 & 2 & 3  \\ 1 & 2 & 3  \\ 1 & 2 & 3  \\ 1 & 2 & 3  \\1 & 2 & 3  \\ 1 & 2 & 3  \\ 1 & 2 & 3  \\ 1 & 2 & 3  \\1 & 2 & 3  \\ 1 & 2 & 3  \\ 1 & 2 & 3  \\ 1 & 2 & 3  \\1 & 2 & 3  \\ 1 & 2 & 3  \\ 1 & 2 & 3  \\ 1 & 2 & 3  \\
\end{longtable}
\end{center}


\begin{table}[t]\centering
\caption{Description of fact-check's article category}
\begin{tabular}{ p{2cm}|p{3cm}|p{5cm}  } \hline
% \begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c|  } \hline
%\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Data Description} \\ \hline

\textbf{Class} & \textbf{Definition} & \textbf{Example} \\  \hline

a & b & c \\ 
 a & b & c \\ 
   a & b & c \\ 
     a & b & c \\   a & b & c \\    
\end{tabular}\centering
\label{table:category}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

But I want 2nd part of 1st table then 2nd table, both should appear on the same page. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is second table placement option. Instead of `[t]` (which require, that table had to be on top of page) you should write for example `[htb]` (which means "here" or "top" or at "bottom" of page):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\setlength\LTcapwidth{12cm}
    \begin{longtable}{p{4cm}|p{4cm}|p{4cm}}
\caption{A simple longtable example}    \\
    \hline
\textbf{First entry} & \textbf{Second entry} & \textbf{Third entry}  \\
    \hline
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{A simple longtable example-- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\
    \hline
\textbf{First entry} & \textbf{Second entry} & \textbf{Third entry}  \\
    \hline
\endhead
    \hline 
\multicolumn{3}{r}{\footnotesize\textit{Continued on next page}}    \\
  \endfoot
    \hline
\endlastfoot
1 & 2 & 3  \\ 1 & 2 & 3  \\ 1 & 2 & 3  \\ 1 & 2 & 3  \\
1 & 2 & 3  \\ 1 & 2 & 3  \\ 1 & 2 & 3  \\ 1 & 2 & 3  \\
1 & 2 & 3  \\ 1 & 2 & 3  \\ 1 & 2 & 3  \\ 1 & 2 & 3  \\
1 & 2 & 3  \\ 1 & 2 & 3  \\ 1 & 2 & 3  \\ 1 & 2 & 3  \\
1 & 2 & 3  \\ 1 & 2 & 3  \\ 1 & 2 & 3  \\ 1 & 2 & 3  \\
1 & 2 & 3  \\ 1 & 2 & 3  \\ 1 & 2 & 3  \\ 1 & 2 & 3  \\
1 & 2 & 3  \\ 1 & 2 & 3  \\ 1 & 2 & 3  \\ 1 & 2 & 3  \\
1 & 2 & 3  \\ 1 & 2 & 3  \\ 1 & 2 & 3  \\ 1 & 2 & 3  \\
1 & 2 & 3  \\ 1 & 2 & 3  \\ 1 & 2 & 3  \\ 1 & 2 & 3  \\
1 & 2 & 3  \\ 1 & 2 & 3  \\ 1 & 2 & 3  \\ 1 & 2 & 3  \\
1 & 2 & 3  \\ 1 & 2 & 3  \\ 1 & 2 & 3  \\ 1 & 2 & 3  \\
1 & 2 & 3  \\ 1 & 2 & 3  \\ 1 & 2 & 3  \\ 1 & 2 & 3  \\
1 & 2 & 3  \\ 1 & 2 & 3  \\ 1 & 2 & 3  \\ 1 & 2 & 3  \\
    \end{longtable}
\endgroup


    \begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
\caption{Description of fact-check's article category}
\label{table:category}
\begin{tabular}{ p{2cm}|p{3cm}|p{5cm}  } 
    \hline
\textbf{Class} & \textbf{Definition} & \textbf{Example} \\  
    \hline
a & b & c \\
a & b & c \\
a & b & c \\
a & b & c \\   
a & b & c \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate text borders)

`longtable` is always horizontally centered in text area, therefore not  need to be inside `center` area.

Comment: I think `[hb]` placement would be more to the point. (Or `[hbp]`, but not allow `t`.)

Comment: @DonaldArseneau, you are right, if the second table will have space to be on the same page as last part of `longtable. If it hasn't, then is sensible, that it will appear on the top of the next page. I will correct code that it will follows to explanation, where i suggest `htb` options for table float placement. Thank you for tips.

Comment: Indeed, if the next page is needed, then the `t` possibility will be necessary. But we don't want `t` placement above part of the longtable. Hmm... sounds like a case of the flafter package plus the `[htb]` placement options.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue arises because you combining 2 different table format, but once you convert second table to longtable it will be resolved.

```
\begin{longtable}{p{4cm}|p{4cm}|p{4cm}}
\caption{Description of fact-check's article category}\\
\textbf{Class} & \textbf{Definition} & \textbf{Example} \\  \hline

 a & b & c \\ 
 a & b & c \\ 
 a & b & c \\ 
 a & b & c \\   
 a & b & c \\   

 \label{table:category}
 \end{longtable}
```